# How to convert DMS to DD to certain columns in an array that start "lat" or "long"?

Tags: python

I have an array with columns called "lat_formatted" and "long_formatted". The format of the latitude and longitude are degree, minute, seconds & ten thousands of second, declination. For example, latitude is formatted as DD-MM-SS.SSSSH and longitude is formatted as DDD-MM-SS.SSSSH where DD is degrees, MM is minutes, SS.SSSS is seconds and ten thousandths of seconds, and H is declination (51-53-00.8954N). How do I convert this to degree decimals?

Tried breaking it down by index but it won't work.

```
for line in my_array:
    if line.startswith('lat' or 'long')
        lat_degree_formatted = line[0:2]
        lat_min_formatted = line[3:5]
        lat_sec_formatted = line[6:13]
        lat_direction = line[14]

        new_min_formatted = lat_min_formatted / float(60)
        new_sec_formatted = lat_sec_formatted / float(3600)

        new_lat = lat_degree_formatted + new_min_formatted + new_sec_formatted + lat_direction

        my_array.append(new_lat)
```

The code won't run.

Comment: You are missing a ``:`` at the end of the second line.

Comment: `line.startswith('lat' or 'long')` should probably be `line.startswith('lat') or line.startswith('long')`.